# Relating Trace and determinant of dynamic matrices to stability of ODE in high dimension

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given a n-dimensional linear system of ODEs

$y' = Ay + b$

where $A$ is an $n \times n$ square matrix of coefficients dependent on model parameters.

Can we deduce anything about the stability and dynamics of the system based on the trace and the determinant of matrix $A$, that is valid for any $n$? Specifically, for example, what can we deduce if the trace is negative?

I cannot seem to find properties of ODE systems beyond $2$ and $3$ dimensions.

Comment: For example, if the trace is positive, we can say there exist eigenvalues with positive real parts which makes the system unstable?

Comment: Trace and determinant give only 2 of the $n$ coefficients of the characteristic polynomial. Its roots, the eigenvalues, depend on all the coefficients, also in their characterization. If the eigenvalues are all real, for instance if $A$ is symmetric, then the leading 2 coefficients can be used to compute the sum of squares of the eigenvalues and thus a size estimate.